# DGV Lookup Filename in SQL display results

Tags: c#

I'm populating a DGV in C# WinForms with XML filenames which works a treat

```
String folderPath = @"filePath";
DGVSurveysIn.DataSource = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetFiles();
```

The filenames (excluding the .xml) are unique ID's in a SQL table.
Is it possible to add new columns to the same DGV where I lookup data from the SQL table WHERE ID = filename?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Build a class containing the needed informations and query your database, fetch the results in a collection of that class and use it as `DataSource`

Comment: I would create a DataTable (Using an adapter) from the SQL results.  Then you can filter (and join if necessary) before putting into a DGV.  The data table can then be the data source of the DGV.